# Centrar contenido de una celda itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itextsharp

Estoy trabajando en un formato de liquidación de sueldo en c#, con itexsharp para generar el archivo pdf. Pero no consigo controlar la alineación del contenido de las celdas de PdfPTable/PdfPCell.

Tengo este código:

```
            /*datos del LA LIQUIDACIÓN*/
            //1° linea
            phrase.Font = new Font(FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD));
            phrase.Add("H A B E R E S");
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
            cell2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            cell2.PaddingTop = -7;
            cell2.AddElement(phrase);
            cell2.Colspan = 3;
            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
            table2.AddCell(cell2);                
            phrase.Clear();
```

Pero me da este resultado (captura del archivo):
El contenido de la celda en donde se encuentra por ejemplo el texto "HABERES", necesito que sea alineado al centro, pero esta alineado a la izquierda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He conseguido la respuesta, gracias a Bruno Lowagie quién es uno de los creadores de la documentación de itext. Existen 2 maneras de organizar el contenido en estos casos:
 Primero organizandolo a nivel de celda, que en este caso no funciona, ya que la celda utiliza la alineación general y elimina la alineación individualizada, por ende se pasa al segundo modo.
 Segundo, organizandolo a nivel general o de texto, para ello en la clase Phrase no he encontrado una definición para modificar la propiedad de alineamiento horizontal, por lo que puedes cambiarlo a la clase Paragraph.

Reemplazando el código, por el siguiente:

```
            /*datos del LA LIQUIDACIÓN*/
            //1° linea
            paragraph.Clear();//ahora utilizo la clase Paragraph 
            paragraph.Font = new Font(FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD));
            paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            paragraph.Add("H A B E R E S");
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
            cell2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            cell2.PaddingTop = -7;
            cell2.AddElement(paragraph);
            cell2.Colspan = 3;
            table2.AddCell(cell2);
            paragraph.Clear();
```

Obtendrías este resultado:

[image]